# Power serie of $f'/f$

Tags: power-series

It seems that I'm [censored] blind in searching the power series expansion of $$f(x):=\frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x+4}$$ in $x=0$.

I've tried a lot, e.g., partiell fraction decomposition, or regarding $f(x)=\left(\log((x+1)^2+3)\right)'$ -- without success.

I' sure that I'm overseeing a tiny little missing link; dear colleagues, please give me a hint.

Comment: Loving the `censored`. Can't you just differentiate again and again and try to spot a pattern between the successive derivatives?

Comment: what about$\frac{2t}{t^2+3}$ and expansion to complex values (partial fraction decomposition)?

Comment: Have you tried a partial fraction decomposition?

Comment: @Khallil Of course I did.  I've  quitted that job at $f'''$ ...

Comment: @Cardinal Of course I did, but I've ended up with the sum of two geometric series which I was unable to reduce to reel coefficients. --

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series+of+%282+x+-+2%29%2F%28x^2+-+2+x+%2B+4%29%2C+x%3D0), which seems to correspond to $\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k+1} x^{3k}}{2^{3 k + 1}} \left(1 - \frac{x}{2} - \frac{x^2}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 2):

The given $f(x)$ is given by
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{2(x-1)}{x^2 - 2x + 4}
\end{align}
and can be seen as, where $a = 1 + \sqrt{3} i$ and $b = 1 - \sqrt{3} i$, such that $ab=4$,
\begin{align}
f(x) = \frac{-2 \, (1 - x)}{ab \, \left(1 - \frac{x}{a}\right) \left( 1 - \frac{x}{b}\right)}
\end{align}
for which
\begin{align}
\ln f(x) &= \ln\left(- \frac{4}{ab}\right) + \ln(1 - x) - \ln\left(1 - \frac{x}{a}\right) - \ln\left(1 - \frac{x}{b}\right) \\
&= \pi i - \ln 2 + \ln(1 - x) - \ln\left(1 - \frac{x}{a}\right) - \ln\left(1 - \frac{x}{b}\right) \\
&= \pi i - \ln 2 - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{a^{n}} - \frac{1}{b^{n}} \right) \, \frac{x^{n}}{n} \\
&= \pi i - \ln 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{a^{n} + b^{n}}{4^{n}} - 1 \right) \, \frac{x^{n}}{n} \\
&= \pi i - \ln 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a^{n} + b^{n} - 4^{n} }{n} \, \left(\frac{x}{4}\right)^{n} \\
&= \pi i - \ln 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ 2 \, \cos\left(\frac{n \pi }{3}\right) - 2^{n} }{n} \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n}.
\end{align}
Now differentiating both sides leads to
\begin{align}
\frac{f'}{f} &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left( 2 \, \cos\left(\frac{n \pi }{3}\right) - 2^{n} \right) \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(2 \, \cos\left(\frac{n \pi}{3}\right) - 2^{n} \right) \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n-1} \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left( \cos\left(\frac{(n+1) \pi}{3}\right) - 2^{n} \right) \, \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{n}.
\end{align}
Expanding the first few terms provides
\begin{align}
- \frac{f'}{f} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{5 \, x}{4} + \frac{5 \, x^{2}}{4} + \frac{17 \, x^{3}}{16} + \frac{31 \, x^{4}}{32} + \mathcal{O}(x^{5}) 
\end{align}

Comment: The function should contain $2(x-1)$ and not $2(x-2)$... That $2$ propagates to the solution, but should be $1$...

Comment: @johannesvalks Thanks for pointing out the error. Apparently $x-2$ does not equal $x-1$.

Comment: Your welcome...

Answer (score 2):

Given

> $$
> f(x) = \frac{ 2 x - 2 }{ x^2 - 2 x + 4 }. \tag 1
> $$

Assuming you want to expand $f(x)$.

Let
$$
\phi_\pm = 1 \pm \mathtt{i} \sqrt{3}. \tag 2
$$
We can write (1) as
$$
f(x) =
   \frac{ 1 }{ x - \phi_+ } + 
   \frac{ 1 }{ x - \phi_- }. \tag 3
$$

Whence
$$
f(x) =
   - \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(
      \frac{1}{{\phi_+}^{k+1}} +
      \frac{1}{{\phi_-}^{k+1}}
   \right) x^k. \tag 4
$$

Note that
$$
\phi_\pm = 1 \pm \mathtt{i} \sqrt{3} =
   2 {\exp}\big( \pm \mathtt{i} \pi / 3 \big). \tag 5
$$

Putting (5) in (4) yields

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] {
>    \frac{ 2 x - 2 }{ x^2 - 2 x + 4 } =
>       - \sum_{k=0}^\infty {\cos}\big( [k+1] \pi / 3 \big)
>       \left( \frac{x}{2} \right)^k.
> } \tag {I}
> $$

Simple expansion yields

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] { \frac{ 2 x - 2 }{ x^2 - 2 x + 4 } =
>    - \frac{1}{2}
>    + \frac{x}{4} + \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{x^3}{16}
>    - \frac{x^4}{32} - \frac{x^5}{32} - \frac{x^6}{128}
>    + \cdots
> } \tag{II}
> $$

---

Note that
$$
f(x) = \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}, \tag 6
$$
where
$$
g(x) = x^2 - 2x + 4. \tag 7
$$

If you want to expand
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}, \tag 8
$$

then use the simple relation
$$
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \frac{g''(x)}{g'(x)} - \frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}. \tag 9
$$

Note that
$$
\frac{g''(x)}{g'(x)} = \frac{2x}{2x-2} = - \sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k \tag {10}.
$$

Combination with (II) yields

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] {
>    \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} =
>       + \sum_{k=0}^\infty \left(
>          2^{-k} {\cos}\big( [k+1] \pi / 3 \big) - 1
>       \right)
>       x^k.
> } \tag {III}
> $$

Simple expansion yields

> $$
> \bbox[16px,border:2px solid #800000] { \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} =
>    - \frac{1}{2}
>    - \frac{5x}{4} - \frac{5x^2}{4} - \frac{17x^3}{16}
>    - \frac{31x^4}{32} - \frac{31x^5}{32} - \frac{127x^6}{128}
>    \cdots
> } \tag{IV}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

You could try noting
$$\frac{1}{(x-2)^{2}}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-(x/2)}\right)$$
Then 
$$f(x)=2(x-1)\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-(x/2)}\right)$$
lends itself to a power-series expansion immediately...

Comment: But the denominator doesn't equal $(x-2)^2$ ...

Answer (score 0):

Given any function $f$, if we restrict to where $f$ is nonzero (so that either $\log f$ or $\log -f$ exists), we can write $\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{d}{dt}\log |f|$.    If $f=c \prod (x-\alpha_i)^{k_i}$ is a rational function, $\log f = \log c +  \sum k_i \log (x-\alpha_i)$ and so 
$$\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{d}{dt}\log |f| = \sum k_i \frac{1}{x-\alpha}.$$

Now, use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum x^i$, and the factorization that $(2x-2)/(x^2−2x+4)= 2(x-1)(x-1+\sqrt{3})^{-1}(x-1-\sqrt{3})^{-1}$.

Answer (score -1):

Since
$$
x^2-2x+4=(x-1)^2+3=(x-2u)(x-2\bar{u}),
$$
with
$$
u=e^{i\frac\pi3},
$$
we have
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=&\frac{2x-2}{(x-2u)(x-2\bar{u})}=\frac{1}{x-2u}+\frac{1}{x-2\bar{u}}=-\frac{\bar{u}}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{\bar{u}}{2}x}-\frac{u}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{u}{2}x}\\
&=&-\frac{\bar{u}}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\bar{u}}{2}\right)^nx^n-\frac{u}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)^nx^n
=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{\bar{u}}{2}\right)^{n+1}x^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)^{n+1}x^n\\
&=&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{u^{n+1}+\bar{u}^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}}x^n=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\cos\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\pi\right)x^n.
\end{eqnarray}
Also
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}&=&\left[\ln |f(x)|\right]'=[\ln2+\ln|x-1|-\ln|x^2-2x+4|]'\\
&=&\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{2x-2}{x^2-2x+4}=-\frac{1}{1-x}-f(x)\\
&=&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\cos\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\pi\right)x^n\\
&=&-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left[1+\frac{1}{2^n}\cos\left(\frac{n+1}{3}\pi\right)\right]x^n.
\end{eqnarray}